# Laravel "[Vue warn]: Error compiling template" When Using Dump

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a simple Blade template. When trying to dump() the contents of a PHP array, I'm getting an "Error compiling template" error from Vue. Laravel version: 7.15. This happens if I use the Blade directive @dump, too.

### Blade Template

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<?php
$cars = [ 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota' ];

dump( $cars );
?>
   
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Welcome!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

### Error in Browser Console

```
app.js:37361 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

48 |            
49 |            
50 |  
   |   
51 |  <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else { n = /\bsf-dump-ellipsis\b/.test(e.target.className) ? e.target.parentNode : e.target; if ((n = n.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling || n; } f(n, e, true); } } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) {
warn @ app.js:37361
(anonymous) @ app.js:47465
compileToFunctions @ app.js:47464
Vue.$mount @ app.js:47679
Vue._init @ app.js:41294
Vue @ app.js:41361
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:47836
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:47963
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:91
(anonymous) @ app.js:93
app.js:37361 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.

49 |            
50 |  
51 |  <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else { n = /\bsf-dump-ellipsis\b/.test(e.target.className) ? e.target.parentNode : e.target; if ((n = n.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling || n; } f(n, e, true); } } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click',
warn @ app.js:37361
(anonymous) @ app.js:47465
compileToFunctions @ app.js:47464
Vue.$mount @ app.js:47679
Vue._init @ app.js:41294
Vue @ app.js:41361
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:47836
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:47963
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:91
(anonymous) @ app.js:93
app.js:37361 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

54 |    <span class="sf-dump-index">2</span> =&gt; "<span class="sf-dump-str" title="6 characters">Toyota</span>"
55 |  </samp>]
56 |  </pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1880964245")</script>
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
57 |  
   |  
58 |  <div class="container">
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
59 |    <div class="row justify-content-center">
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
60 |        <div class="col-md-8">
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
61 |            <div class="card">
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
62 |                <div class="card-body">
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
63 |                    Welcome!
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
64 |                </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^
65 |            </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^
66 |        </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^
67 |    </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^
68 |  </div>
   |  ^^^^^^
69 |  
   |  
70 |        </main>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^
71 |    </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^
```

As you can see, I'm not doing anything complicated. Why am I getting this error when using dump() or @dump()? Thank you.

Comment: dump, is like dd, right? so it would include a whole bunch of dom, styling and scripts which you can see from the error, which vue does not allow in-line. work out a diff way in dumping your value, `echo '<pre>'.print_r($cars, true).'</pre>';`.. though you should aim to debug in vue after passing the value to it `<pre>{{ cars }}</pre>`, if not a simple `console.log(vm.cars)` etc.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, it's just like dd() except it doesn't die. dd() actually works without a problem, but I want to be able to use dump().

Answer (score 0):

`@dump()` is a Blade directive (to be used as it is), while you are wrapping it in PHP tags.

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump), this should also work: `{{ dump($value) }}`.

Comment: That doesn't help. If I go to line 37,361 of the compiled app.js, all it has is: console.error('[Vue warn]: ' + msg + trace); Also, using @php instead of <?php doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try the `@dump()` directive elsewhere in the Blade template; eg. `div.card-body`.